# Ajax location method does not load Form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

```
function purchase() {
    var url = '<%: Url.AbsoluteRouteUrl("packages", new { action = "PrePaidPurchaseWithStoredCc", controller = "packages" })%>';
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: url,
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: { ownerKey: selOwnerKey, providerKey: selProviderKey, packageKey: selPackageKey, creditCardId: $("#creditCardId").val(), embedded: true },
          success: function (response) {
           window.location = Sys.Url.route('packages', { action: "provider", controller: "packages", providerKey: '<%: Model.Provider.Key %>', ownerKey: '<%: Model.Owner.Key %>' });
            }
         });
       }
```

I need to load the whole form when having success callback.But unfortunately above code is not working.When I put `window.location` code before ajax call it's working.

Why is above way not working ?

Comment: what does this `Sys.Url.route()` method returns?

Comment: @Mahan it's calling relevant action method.

Comment: Does the `.success()` method ever called? If you put `alert()` there you see it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes.Only windows.location is not working.When I put that outside the ajax call it's also working.

Comment: Wait... what exactly you mean by "not working"? Do you see the document loading something? When you do `alert(Sys.Url.route('packages', { action: "provider", controller: "packages", providerKey: '<%: Model.Provider.Key %>', ownerKey: '<%: Model.Owner.Key %>' }));` do you see the correct URL?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes.URL is correct.I verified it by using firebug.The thing is page is not loading when I put it inside the .success() method.When I put it Out side the ajax call page loads as I expect.Is there any hidden tec issue behind this ?

Comment: Nothing I can think of... try changing to `document.location.href = Sys.Url.route(...);` though it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes.You're right.My .success() method is also not firing.Problem is on my action method.It is not returning any json result.Rather it redirects to another action.When I correct that above code is working.Thanks for support.

Comment: So it's solved now? In such case either share the solution or delete the question. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes sure I will share the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Wrong** Action Method is as below :

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PrePaidPurchaseWithStoredCc(string ownerKey, string providerKey)
     {   
      return RedirectToAction("Provider", new { providerKey = providerKey, ownerKey = ownerKey });
     }
```

When I **changed** it to like below.It's working:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PrePaidPurchaseWithStoredCc(string ownerKey, string providerKey)
  {   
    return Json(string.Empty, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

**Page Re-load** jQuery Function is as below :

```
function purchase() {
    var url = '<%: Url.AbsoluteRouteUrl("packages", new { action = "PrePaidPurchaseWithStoredCc", controller = "packages" })%>';
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: url,
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: { ownerKey: selOwnerKey, providerKey: selProviderKey, packageKey: selPackageKey, creditCardId: $("#creditCardId").val(), embedded: true },
          success: function (response) {
           window.location = Sys.Url.route('packages', { action: "provider", controller: "packages", providerKey: '<%: Model.Provider.Key %>', ownerKey: '<%: Model.Owner.Key %>' });
            }
         });
       }
```

**Note :** *The problem was my action method didn't have a json return.B'cos of that it does not fire  .success: method.*